# Very slow when bringing pictures to "Android gridview" with "Glide"

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, android-glide

I'm making a gallery app with on Android Studio. I'm using gridview to show pictures. I'm using Database Firebase. I use the Glide API to download and display images in the project. But the pictures are loading too late. I'm looking at similar applications on Google Play, this applications load their pictures very fast. Below is my code, how would you suggest a solution?

```
public class imageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mList;
    ImageView mImageView;
    int pos=0;

public imageAdapter(Context context,List<String> list) {
    mContext = context;
    mList = list;
}
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    pos=position;
    if (convertView == null) {
        mImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 500));
        mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        mImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
 Glide.with(mContext).load(mList.get(pos)).override(350,500).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).placeholder(R.drawable.loading2).dontAnimate().dontTransform().into(mImageView);
    return mImageView;
}
```

}

Comment: where do you load them from?

Answer (score 0):

Because when created a view object implemented change view

You can use RecycelerView in GridViewLayoutManager, that's very optimized for loading many items in one list with diff layoutManager

Set GridView as a layoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```

Implemented recycelerViewAdapter with creating a new instance form this and change view content in onBindViewHolder method

```
 // binds the data to the TextView in each cell
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   Glide.with(mContext).load(mList.get(pos)).override(350,500)
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
   .placeholder(R.drawable.loading2).dontAnimate()
   .dontTransform().into(holder.mImageView);
}
```

Create or find view in viewHoler

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mImageView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    }
}
```

This [article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager) is useful for implementation GridView with recycelerView

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.popular_list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}


 @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
   Picasso.get()
                .load(image_path).placeholder(R.mipmap.your_placeholder)
                .error(R.mipmap.error_icon).fit()
                .into(holder.imageView);
}
  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   public TextView txtRecipeName,txtprice;
        ImageView imagview
  public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            imagview= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagview);
        }
    }
```

please implement following delegates then you will able to get image using Picasso or Glide perfectly.